# ERR_TIMED_OUT on google chrome

Tags: windows-7

I have windows7 home premium and can no longer log into net flix   I receive
ERR_TIMED_OUT  using google as my web browser.  This is a new problem for me
Up until 48 hours ago I never had any problems

Comment: This means that you can't connect to Netflix.com (which you can safely spell out here). Try this: Open the Start Menu and search `CMD`. Open the result and type `ping netflix.com`, before hitting `ENTER`. If that times out, you either have something wrong with your network or you need to reboot.

Comment: What dns nameservers are you using? try googleDNS or openDNS  8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4 OR 4.2.2.2 / 208.67.222.222 respectively

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem when I choose another ISP. I thought I would have only to put my new ID and password, but it wasn't the case.
I have an ADSL modem with a dry loop.

All others services were fine (DNS resolution, IP telephony, FTP, etc).
I did a lot of tests (disable firewall, try some others navigator, try under linux, modem default factory, etc) none of those tests wre successfull.

To resolve the problem ERR_TIMED_OUT, I had to ajusted the MTU and MRU values. I put 1458 rather than 1492, which is the default value. 
It works for me. Maybe some ISP used others values. Good luck.